# vscode extension development: Add user defined data to vscode extension when package

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I'm new to javascript and vscode extension development.
I'm trying to write a vscode extension, doing execSync a python script.
The file structure:

```sh
src:
  |-- extension.ts
  |-- sidebar_test.ts
  |-- test_py.py
```

the content of extension.js file:

```js
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import * as sidebar from './sidebar_test';
import * as cp from "child_process";


// this method is called when your extension is activated
// your extension is activated the very first time the command is executed
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
  console.log('process cwd: ', process.cwd(), '. env: ', process.env);
  console.log('extension path: ', context.extensionPath);

  // The command has been defined in the package.json file
  // Now provide the implementation of the command with registerCommand
  // The commandId parameter must match the command field in package.json
  let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('dp2000-upgrade.DP2000Upgrade', function () {
      vscode.window.showInputBox({
          ignoreFocusOut: true,
          placeHolder: 'IP Addr:Port',
        }).then(function (input_str) {
          let options = { env: {LD_LIBRARY_PATH: '/data/huangxiaofeng/work/tvm0.9dev0/build', PYTHONPATH: '/data/huangxiaofeng/work/tvm0.9dev0/python'} };
          cp.execSync(`python ./test_py.py ${input_str}`, options); // TODO: call python script test_py.py
        }).then(function (msg) {
          console.log('User input:' + msg);
        });
    });

  context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}

// this method is called when your extension is deactivated
export function deactivate(): void {}
```

the content of test_py.py:

```py
#! /usr/bin/python3.6
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import tvm
import sys
import tvm.rpc

print('test_py.py will run...')
ip_addr, ip_port = sys.argv[1].split(':')
remote = tvm.rpc.connect(ip_addr, int(ip_port))
add_func = remote.get_function('rpc.test_add')
print(add_func(10, 20))
```

The content of package.json

```json
{
    "name": "dp2000-upgrade",
    "displayName": "DP2000升级插件Demo",
    "description": "vscode插件Demo, 借助TVM实现远程刷写 NNP main.hex",
    "publisher": "intellif",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "engines": {
        "vscode": "^1.63.0"
    },
    "categories": [
        "Other"
    ],
    "activationEvents": [
    "onCommand:dp2000-upgrade.DP2000Upgrade",
        "onView:sidebar_test_id1"
    ],
    "main": "./out/extension.js",
    "contributes": {
        "commands": [
            {
                "command": "dp2000-upgrade.DP2000Upgrade",
                "title": "Upgrade DP2000"
            }
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "vscode:prepublish": "npm run compile",
        "compile": "tsc -p ./",
        "watch": "tsc -watch -p ./",
        "pretest": "npm run compile && npm run lint",
        "lint": "eslint src --ext ts",
        "package": "npm ci && rimraf *.vsix && vsce package && vsce ls"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/vscode": "^1.63.0",
        "@types/glob": "^7.2.0",
        "@types/mocha": "^9.0.0",
        "@types/node": "14.x",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.9.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.9.1",
        "eslint": "^8.6.0",
        "glob": "^7.2.0",
        "mocha": "^9.1.3",
        "typescript": "^4.5.4",
        "@vscode/test-electron": "^2.0.3"
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://gitee.com/vaughnHuang/vscode_ext_sidebar_test"
    }
}
```

When package the project to .vsix, the test_py.py not included.

So my question is: how to include src/test_py.py into the .vsix?

Comment: edit your question, not by adding an answer, who has written `test_py.py`

Comment: Is there anything in the `vscodeignore` file that would exclude it?

Comment: @rioV8 Thanks for your tips. I tried several times, and when I paste the package.json into the question, it always blame that there's some problem and need format.

Answer (score 0):

Your file is probably being ignored by the `.vscodeignore` file, which determines what files to exclude from the vsix.

See https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension#using-.vscodeignore